# Changing core data predicate from setEditing

Tags: uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, editing, reloaddata

My app maintains a list of data of which some rows may be hidden by the user.  The hide/show button is in an editing panel that is accessed by putting the tableview into editing mode and then selecting the row to be edited.  This means that in editing mode all rows need to show up, even those that are normally hidden; otherwise there would be no way to unhide them.

I implemented this by setting fetchedResultsController to nil and reloading the table within setEditing, and then modifying the code that builds the predicate for the fetchedResultsController to check if the table is in editing mode and if so, skipping the part of the predicate that excludes hidden lists.  So when the user touches the Edit button the table reloads with all rows on the way into editing mode, and reloads again with only unhidden rows on the way back out.

This works fine except that it has killed the animation one usually sees while going into and out of editing mode.  The extra reload has made it look abrupt.  It makes no difference if I do the reload before or after the call to [super setEditing:animated].

Is there a better way or place to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your CD object include a visibility attribute. When you go into editing mode, flip the attributes for all hidden cells. Make the predicate for the fetchedResultsController include the visibility attribute. It will automatically add the table cells if you have implemented the call-backs.

Comment: This worked, thanks! It's not 100% smooth, as the table is updating at the same time as it's going into editing mode, but I think it's probably the best it can be.  Still perplexed why the other Steve's suggestion didn't work, though.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

**Modifying the Fetch Request**
You cannot simply change the fetch request to modify the results. If you want to change the fetch request, you must:

1. If you are using a cache, delete it (using deleteCacheWithName:).
   Typically you should not use a cache if you are changing the fetch
   request.
2. Change the fetch request.
3. Invoke performFetch:

See if that works better, vs. destroying the controller and reloading the table.

Comment: The table doesn't update after the performFetch, unless I use reload which is what I'm trying to avoid.  Is there something else I need to do to make that happen?